# Python context manager for importing modules outside my local directory

Tags: python, context-manager

I implemented this context manager for importing modules from arbitrary directories.

Good? Bad? - Keen to get thoughts:

## Implementation

```py
import sys 

class CustomPath:
    def __init__(self, path:str):
        self.original_path = sys.path
        self.custom_path = path 
        
    def __enter__(self):
        sys.path.insert(0, self.custom_path)
        
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        sys.path = self.original_path
```

## Usage

Consider this directory structure:

```
 - project1
    |- notebooks/
         |- notebook1.ipynb
 - project2
 - ...
 - project5/
    |-somefiles/
          |- common_utils.py
```

I can run this in the notebook1.ipynb and it works:

```py
with CustomPath('../../project5/somefiles/'):
   from common_utils import connect_to_db
```

Comment: Interesting, but have you considered the importlib module?

Comment: I did, but I could not get it to work, probably due to relative imports.

Comment: Do you see any potential problems if this were used in a multithreaded application, specifically with two threads doing doing imports with your context manager?

Comment: Honestly no idea, it never occurred to me to import things inside a thread.

Comment: I don't believe that your code would be thread-safe and that could limit its utility in the future.